# ¿Cómo definir un rango o intervalo de 1 a 100 javascript? ¿[1..100]?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo se define un rango en JavaScript usando corchetes? Quiero un "array" de 1..100 sin tener que hacer [1,2,3,4,5,etc] ¿hay alguna forma tipo [1..100], [1...100] o [1, ..100]?
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma usando corchetes de hacer esto sin funciones externas.

Comment: Me temo que no la hay, pero aquí tienes un montón de formas -algunas bastante ingeniosas- de lograrlo sin usar un loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe una función `range()` como en otros lenguajes de programación, pero se puede [de otras formas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559488/1545868), por ejemplo (ES2015 o superior):

```javascript
> Array.from({length:100}, (x, i) => i);
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 99]
```

Edit - Para usar un inicio/final, se puede modificar la expresión anterior:

```javascript
> let inicio=3, final=10
> Array.from({length:final-inicio}, (x, i)=>i+inicio);
[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

Comment: Realmente me interesaría del 1..100, en este caso podría ponerle Array.from({length:100}, (x, i) => i + 1); a tu ejemplo y me valdría. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias @David, modifiqué la respuesta con tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un array con longitud `100` y al usar el método [**`keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) obtienes un iterador con los índices del arreglo (o sea los índices como elementos del array). Ejemplo:

```js
let arr = [...Array(100).keys()]
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: le doy 1 voto a esta, tendrá peor semántica pero tiene mejor performance